# Connection to postgresql not working as expected

Tags: c#, postgresql, odbc, oledb

Again I am facing a problem retrieving data from a database system - this time I'm trying to connect to Postgresql.

I installed a postgresql Server locally and created a sample database. I can connect to the server and query data via the postgres command window - so far so good.

Furthermore - after unsuccessfully trying to get a working free OleDB provider - I installed the ODBC Drivers for Unicode in 32 bit and 64 bit version. Using the ODBC Datasource managers (64 and 32 bit) I can create ODBC Sources - connection succeeds.

Now what does NOT work: according to connectionstring.com, it should be possible to connect to the server with a regular connectionstring, providing servername, UID, PWD and so on. Trying to connect to the Server via Connectionstring, I receive the message `Data source name not found and no default driver specified`. If I define the connectionstring with the ODBC Data Source, everything works fine.

As far as I understood, this should be possible WITHOUT the need to define a ODBC Datasource for each and every database. Since the application will dynamically connect to something like 20-50 Databases, it would be great, if I could stick to the dynamic connection strings instead of the datasources.

Additional: I managed to get the connection working with npgsql, but nevertheless it would be great to use OleDB (which I gave hope up to get it running...) or ODBC with the Connectionstrings without additional manual effort for each DB.

Comment: Use the ODBC Administrator to create a File DSN, then open it in Notepad and use the key/value entries in there to create your connection string.

Comment: @GordThompson unfortunately not working... same error as before